# How to change textview font size in recyclerView in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, font-size

How to change textView font size in RecyclerView (from shared preferences)?

I tried to save size in SaveData class:

```
class SaveData(context: Context) {
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences =
        context.getSharedPreferences("file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

fun setFontSize(size: Float?) {
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putFloat("FontSize", size!!)
        editor.apply()
    }

    fun loadFontSize(): Float {
        val size = sharedPreferences.getFloat("FontSize", 0f)
        return size
    }
}
```

What is the code and where put it in Adapter or Activity?

Comment: Is the save/read working? Are you able to get the size value back in `loadFontSize()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I am guessing that you already have some mechanism to store the font size in shared pref. Now, you just need to ask sharedPref from recycler view adapter. To access sharedPref you can use `itemView.getContext()`(in java) or `itemView.context`(in kotlin). Now you have context(lets say you named it `ctx`), you can do this.

```kotlin
val pref= SaveData(ctx)
val fontSize= pref.loadFontSize()
```

Hope this works.